# Gitlab downstream pipelines rules with changes block not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm trying to use changes block inside rules block in the downstream pipeline:

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - "projects/testing/**"
```

When doing it like this the job is not created. If i remove the changes part and just go with:

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

It works just fine. I dont know if i'm missing something here.

Edit. I managed to get it working in the MR pipelines with this code:

```
rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - "projects/demo-app/**"
    - "*.tf"
  when: on_success
- if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
  changes:
    - "projects/demo-app/**"
    - "*.tf"
  when: on_success
- when: never
```

But when change is merged it doesn't trigger the pipeline anymore.

Comment: and what changes are you pushing in the projects/testing/ directory?

Comment: I have .tfvars files there that i have changed.

Comment: are the .tfvars files directly under projects/testing/ or within a subfolder in there?

Comment: They are directly there it might be that the downstream pipelines have limited functionality when it comes to changes. I did modify it little bit and it now works in the merge_request pipeline but not when the change is merged to master. I did update the original post to have this updated workflow

Comment: is this a trigger job?

Comment: Yes this is triggered from the parent